# How can split a string using a special symbol by dealing with white spaces and return all matches?

Tags: python, string, list, split, whitespace

I have a string in Python with the value 'I take $80 from you and give you $ 100 back.'. Notice the difference between the two monetary values here. There is no white space between the '$' symbol and value in '$80' but there is a space between '$' and value in '$ 100'.

And I want to return a list which looks like ['$80', '$100'] or ['$80', '$ 100']. How can I achieve this using Python?

```
>>> text = 'I take $80 from you and give you $ 100 back.'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\$\s*\d+', text)
['$80', '$ 100']
```

Comment: Please see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "*Show me how to solve this coding problem*" [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You have to [make an honest attempt at the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression, and find the numbers that start with `$` sign with zero or more white space character:

```py
>>> text = 'I take $80 from you and give you $ 100 back.'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\$\s*\d+', text)
['$80', '$ 100']
```

If you don't need the whitespace after `$` sign, then you can try to capture the numbers only, then add `$` in front of it later:

```py
>>> ['$'+v for v in re.findall('\$\s*(\d+)', text)]
['$80', '$100']
```